# How to place image in GridView at different positions in Android?

Tags: android, gridview

I am using GridView having three columns, in my app. You can see it below.

```
<GridView
                android:id="@+id/mainMenu"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:columnWidth="60dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:numColumns="3"
                android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
                android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
                android:verticalSpacing="1dp" >
```

Dynamically I want to place 6-images at six different positions in GridView. I have developed some code in this respect, every time when I run the code, it places the images at wrong positions. Actually I want to place image_1 at position_0, image_2 at position_1, image_3 at position_2 and so on. How can I achieve the desired task. Please help me in this respect I would be very thankful to you for this act of kindness. Thanks in advance.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT); 
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON); 

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    grdMainMenu = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.mainMenu);
    grdMainMenu.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
}



public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter
    {
        Context mContext;
        public ImageAdapter(Context c)
        {
            mContext = c;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 6;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
        {
            View v;
            ImageView iv;

            if(convertView ==null)
            {
                LayoutInflater li = getLayoutInflater();
                v = li.inflate(R.layout.icon, null);

                iv = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.icon_image);

                if(position == 0)
                {
                    iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.image1);
                }

                if(position == 1)
                {
                    iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.image2);
                }

                if(position == 2)
                {
                    iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.image3);             

                }

                if(position == 3)
                {
                    iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.image4);             

                }

                if(position == 4)
                {
                    iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.image5);             

                }

                if(position == 5)
                {
                    iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.image6);             

                }

            }

            else
            {
                v = convertView;
            }

            return v;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an ImageAdapter class and a Integer array of your images. The Imageadapter would place each image at the required positions in your gridview. See the answer to [Shuffling Gridview items without repeats tried many approaches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15890493/shuffling-gridview-items-without-repeats-tried-many-approaches). Check the answer by SimonSays