# Shuffling Gridview items without repeats tried many approaches

Tags: java, android, arrays, shuffle

I may be losing the will to live. I have been trying to write a method to shuffle images on a Gridview that uses an ImageAdapter. I am inexperienced at Android. I have accessed all questions on this site relating to shuffling arrays with no repeats. I have tested them in a normal Java environment. There are ones that work with no repeats. I have tried changing the array to an Arraylist and used Collections.shuffle. I still get repeats or the emulator has crashed.  I would truly appreciate some insight on this- it's probably something simple but I cannot get it. Here are some of my methods (using code I have found).

```
   public Integer[] myShuffleS(Integer []ji){

    ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();   
    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    while (numbers.size() < 36) {

        int random = randomGenerator.nextInt(35);
        if (!numbers.contains(random)) {
            numbers.add(random);

        }

    }  
    for (int i=0; i<ji.length;i++) {

        ji[i] =ji[numbers.get(i)] ;
    //  i++;
   }
    return ji;
}
```

another

```
        static int[] shuffleArray(int[] ar)
{
  Random rnd = new Random();
 int randomNo = rnd.nextInt()*3;
//  int randomNo = (int)Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
  for (int i = ar.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
  {
  //  int index = rnd.nextInt(i + 1);
      int index = randomNo - 1;
    // Simple swap
    int a = ar[index];
    ar[index] = ar[i];
    ar[i] = a;
  }

  return ar;
}

 public static void shuffleAArray(int[] a) {
   int n = a.length;
   int random = randomInt(0,35);
//  random.nextInt();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int change = i + random;
       swap(a, i, change);
   }
}
```

another

```
  public Integer[] myShuffle( Integer[]jigX){
      boolean found = false;

for (int i = 0; i < jigX.length; i++) {
      do {

        found = false;
      int  temp = randomInt(0,35);
      jigX[i] = temp;
        for (int j = 0; j < i && !found; j++) { 
         if (jigX[j] == temp) 
             found = true;
        } 
      } 
      while (found);

      }

    return jigX;
    }
```

also tried Collections.shuffle and put in the next piece to get the images

```
    myShuffleS(jigX);//or whatever method
 imageView.setImageResource(jigX [position]);
```

If anyone can help wirh this It would be great! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

OK, after some forth and back, looks like your problem is not the shuffling itself. I guess you shuffle more than once, that is why you get the duplicate entries. Make a custom ListAdapter that can shuffle its items.

```
public class MyImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mCtx;
    private List<Integer> mImages;

    public MyImageAdapter(final Context ctx, final List<Integer> images) {
        mCtx = ctx;
        mImages = images;
    }

    public void shuffle() {
        Collections.shuffle(mImages, new Random(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mImages.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(final int position) {
        return mImages.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(final int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) convertView;
        if (iv == null) {
            iv = new ImageView(mCtx);
        }

        iv.setImageResource(mImages.get(position));

        return iv;
    }
}
```

In your activity use it as follows:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.my_layout);

    List<Integer> images = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    images.add(R.drawable.image1);
    images.add(R.drawable.image2);
    images.add(R.drawable.image3);
    ...
    GridView gv = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
    mAdapter = new MyImageAdapter(this, images);
    gv.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    ...    
    mAdapter.shuffle();
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Thanks for responding SimonSays I have tried it many times but I'll give it another go - altho tomorrow

Comment: Thanks SimonSays But it still repeats

Comment: As long as the input array has no repeating numbers, the output array won't have any either with this method. If the input array can contain repeating numbers, then you need to filter them first. You could use a Set for that as an example.

Comment: I don't know what your problem is. The above code works fine. The input array (ia[]) contains numbers from 0 to 9 and gets shuffled. There are no repeating numbers. If that does not work for you then you need to be more specific about what the problem is.

Comment: The problem is that that that is an array of numbers - the array i need to shuffle is an Integer array of image objects If I try to access these objects using a number array I get nothing in return the method used to access the images is

Comment: @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
     
        return jigPieces[position];
     }

Comment: Beth, I'm sorry, but that does not even make sense anymore. "an Integer array of image objects" - so what is it now, an Integer array or an Image Object array? And then "getItem(int position)" sounds like you are using a ListAdapter, but you do not mention that before. I think you need first to figure out what your problem is and how to describe it.

Comment: Yes Simon I am using a ListAdapter I apologise for my inability to explain things correctly. I am making(trying) a basic jigsaw puzzle. There are 36 images in an integer array. These are assigned to a gridview using an imageadapter - when I click a button I want the images to shuffle.Because of my inexperience (3 weeks Android) I just realized unless I assign a random image - not an number - nothing will be returned in the shuffle.

Comment: I have tested methods in eclipse just for java they work fine no repeats when I try them in Android I get duplicate images.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27981/discussion-between-beth-ann-meredith-and-simonsays)

Comment: You're welcome. Please flag the answer as accepted if you're satisfied with it.

Answer (score 0):

If Collections.shufle fails you somehow:

1. Put your integers in Set,
2. take them one by one using random.nextInt(set.size()-1).
3. Add the taken out to a new Arraylist.
4. Continue till the set is empty.

Guarantueed no doubles.

Comment: Thanks for responding but still no joy :-)

Comment: Then I think your problem is not in your shufling mechanism. How can you tell that it does not work? Did you print out out the shuffeled result and saw doubles? Or did you just look at you images? Maybe the error is somewhere else.